# Query working inside a function

Tags: php

I have this code inside a function:

```
function verifica($soph,$ano)
{

        $sql_ver = "SELECT * FROM ativEns WHERE Sophia_ID = ".$soph." and AnoLetivo =".$ano."";
        $lista_ver = sqlsrv_query($ligarBD,$sql_ver);
        $result_ver = sqlsrv_fetch_array($lista_ver);

        if (!$result_ver)
        {
            echo "Nothing.";
        }
        else
        {
            echo $result_ver["desc"];
        }


}
```

To call the function:

```
$temp_ver = substr($anoatual,0,4) . substr($anoatual,5,4);

verifica($sophia,$temp_ver);
```

It works perfectly if not inside the function, but when I put it  in the function it just echoes de "Nothing"

Comment: Did you define `$sophia` too?

Comment: `$ligarBD` is not available in your function.

Answer (score 1):

`$sophia` is undefined inside your function, so

```
$sql_ver = "SELECT * FROM ativEns WHERE Sophia_ID = ".$sophia." and AnoLetivo =".$temp_ver."";
```

is producing a query that looks like

```
SELECT ... WHERE Sophia_ID = and
                            ^-----due to undefined variable.
```

Perhaps it should be just `$soph` instead, to match the arguments in the function definition?

Comment: Yea I copied it wrong, it's now like you said but still not working.

Comment: Perhaps AnoLetivo is a string? therefore the query should be: `$sql_ver = "SELECT * FROM ativEns WHERE Sophia_ID = {$sophia} AND AnoLetivo ='{$temp_ver}'";`?

Comment: What about `$ligarBD`? That's also undefined.

Comment: it is, there's an include on the file, as I said it works it not inside the function.

Comment: exactly. You need to learn about PHP's variable scoping: http://www.php.net//manual/en/language.variables.scope.php

Comment: Got it working, I think it was the $ligarBD being undefined, thank you a lot.